# Paginate Results of Model Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, pagination

I have a problem with pagination in **laravel 5.3**

The code:

```
public function deals()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\ListsDeals', 'list_has_deals' , 'list_id', 'deal_id')->withPivot('list_id');
}


public function form_edit_list( $id ){

    $list = Lists::find( $id );

    PAGINATE THIS -----> $deals = $list->deals;

    $user = User::find( $list->id_user );

    $categoriesArray = ListsCategories::all();

    $featuresArray = ListsFeatures::all();

    $images = ListsGalleries::all();

    return view( "admin.forms.form_edit_list" )
                    ->with( "list", $list )
                    ->withCategoriesArray( $categoriesArray )
                    ->withFeaturesArray( $featuresArray )
                    ->withImages( $images )
                    ->with( "user", $user );                          
    }
```

I have tried this,

```
$deals = $list->deals->paginate(5);
```

How can I paginate the results of deals ?

Because paginate is not a method of that.

Comment: I believe you can add the `paginate()` call to the `deals()` relationship definition (which will paginate *all* uses of it). That may not be ideal, so you can also do `$deals = $list->deals()->paginate();`

Comment: "You're God damn right", many thanks, i forget that.

Comment: I've turned that into an answer, then. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can add the `paginate()` call to the `deals()` relationship definition (which will paginate *all* uses of it).

That may not be ideal, so you can also do `$deals = $list->deals()->paginate();`

`$list->deals` is a collection of items, while `$list->deals()` is an Eloquent query builder instance you can make further adjustments to before fetching the reuslts.